# triplegolf - not only the source code length counts!

Tags: code-golf

The goal of this challenge is to write a program where the length of the following three are exactly the same:

- the length of the source code
- the length of the output it prints to the standard output
- the length of the compiler warnings it generates with the (unmodded) compiler of your choice

**The winner is the shortest code to fulfill all three criteria, and has to be at least 1 character long.**

To spice things up, if the output has less than three different characters, it gets a **5 point penalty** added to the length for each one (so +10 if only a single type, +5 for two).

(Newlines count either as 1 or 2 characters, your choice, but it has to be consistent through all three criteria. Leading and trailing white-spaces are ignored in all lines in all three criteria)

<sub>In case of equal score, the one printing the most interesting result (instead of garbage) is the winner.</sub>

Comment: What is a "type of character"?

Comment: Is compiling with `-Wall` allowed?  Or is that considered "modding" the compiler?

Comment: Also, what if the compiler produces non-warning output (e.g. "Compiling Main") ?  Also, what if the name of the source file appears in warning messages (e.g. "foo.c:1:1: ...") ?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: edited, I don't know if it's clearer now. I wanted to express that `aaaaaaa` is one, `ababbbba` is made of two different characters.

Comment: @Joey Adams: Good question, I should have thought about that. Is it too late to impose a mandatory filename?

Comment: My weapon of choice is VBA, which doesn't really have a compiler and does not output a binary file to run (as is the case for some other languages, I believe). Are there considerations for this, or am I just disqualified by default?

Comment: I wonder if a triple-quine is possible in some language?

Comment: For interpreted languages, we get an output even on occurance of an error, in such a case, are those errors accepted or are only warnings accepted?

Comment: @Joey Adams: by unmodded I meant that modifying your compiler to print the warning you wanted would be obviously cheating. Sorry, I read too much IOCCC and am never paranoid enough about the rules and the possible circumvention of them. :)

Comment: `=p` in ed unfortunately requires a newline.

Comment: If there isn't the special note about newlines and whitespaces, someone may try `=p` in ed on Cygwin or MinGW.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Bash, 23 characters

Error:

```
bash: /: Is a directory
```

Source:

```
echo       $0-$01234;/;
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash-/bin/bash1234
```

### Brainf*ck, 32 characters

This code executes for about 3 seconds and stops and displays the following error and output.

Error:

```
bff: out of memory (-2058691272)
```

Source:

```
+++++[......-]..+[>>>>>>>>>>>>-]
```

Output: (Hexdump)

```
0505 0505 0505 0404 0404 0404 0303 0303
0303 0202 0202 0202 0101 0101 0101 0000
```

### C, 35 characters

Warning:

```
b.c:1:30: warning: division by zero
```

Source and Output:

```
main(){system("cat "__FILE__)/0;;;}
```

### PHP, 50 characters

Warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /tmp/3 on line 1
```

Source and Output:

```
<?php echo (0/0).''.file_get_contents(__FILE__);?>
```

Comment: The bash example is an error, not a warning.

Comment: What compiler are you using for the C solution?

Comment: @breadbox gcc version 4.7.0 20120505 (prerelease) (GCC)

Answer (score 8):

### C - 48 chars

```
main(i){while(++i<49)putchar(i);putchar('\z');}
```

Note: includes a final (Unix-style) newline.

Output from `gcc a.c` reads:

```
a.c:1:41: warning: unknown escape sequence '\z'
```

The output from `a.out` is mostly non-printing chars, so here's what it looks like after piping through hexdump:

```
00000000: 0203 0405 0607 0809 0A0B 0C0D 0E0F 1011  ................
00000010: 1213 1415 1617 1819 1A1B 1C1D 1E1F 2021  .............. !
00000020: 2223 2425 2627 2829 2A2B 2C2D 2E2F 307A  "#$%&'()*+,-./0z
```

Comment: My understanding is that non-printable (whitepace?) are truncated, so this would not count. If that works, I can improve my own answer.

Comment: Control characters aren't usually considered whitespace, except of course for \t ,\n, \r, \f, and sometimes \v. None of these are at the leading or trailing position, so I figured I was safe.

Comment: Any word from the OP on this?

Comment: I think this is perfectly acceptable. They are not whitespace, and in either case this is not ACM to be **that** strict with the requirements. The main reason for this "whitespace rule" was that some IDEs might heavily format their compiler output.

Comment: 47 chars and ascii output: `main(){'\z';int i=32; while(++i<80)putchar(i);}`

Comment: @copy, Or `main(i){i='\z';while(i-->74)putchar(i);}` -- but reducing the program size is actually counter-productive.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, I know I should have prohibited accessing the contents of the file (just as real quines do)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 63 <s>66</s>

```
!function x(){console.log(x+'...');eval(Array(33).join('$'))}()
```

The output is:

```
function x(){console.log(x+'...');eval(Array(33).join('$'))}...
```

In Chrome, the error is:

```
ReferenceError: $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

## Visual Basic .NET, 185

Gee, `vbc` is pretty verbose with its compilation warnings. Anyway, the code is this:

```
Public Module Main
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(New String("a"c,185))
    End Sub

    Public Function A()
        'This is actually just padding.
        'Hi
    End Function
End Module
```

(Note that they're supposed to be tabs, not spaces.)

The output is this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

And the compiler warning is this:

```
warning BC42105: Function 'A' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

    End Function
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(This time, it's actually four spaces, not tabs.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 20 bytes

```sh
<<<   $-$_$_$_$_$_
[
```

The problem we face here is alluded to in a comment above: Zsh prints the **program name** in addition to the line number before every error. The solution here uses a one-character filename to abuse this. 
[I've wrapped it up in a helper script to show exactly what it prints, and used `wc -c` on stderr, stdout, and the source file.](https://tio.run/##fZBBSwMxEIXv@RUPLEYPEeyxrHsRvXrRUwUJ2dEEdhOYSV0o/vfttNuKh9bJIfB475uXbCVOLQRNA/v08myBK7wJwUNS/uoJIXr2oRLDioUX1Ej4TD1lP9AdXmMSRGLqSsDIqdLsCKUj1PLrhkyN7gAWbvFxOmY96U5TeZODrwQncPdaRjswDeVbCexTr0WQadRbWVyGA9BsJap12aK9qaT82hEz2uvlLX5wVMqmGkMhlr0O@zCPnSWXYR9PrxOUfGSs8B7sPmDGABfQ/GH/k9RdZ5OqX0ymPH8OziRxGJWmHQ)

Output: `569Xcatcatcatcatcat` followed by a newline
Errors: `s:[:2: ']' expected` followed by a newline

---

EDIT: 
Alternate 20 byte solution with no file restriction:

```sh
<<<$-$-$-$-$_>&1 >&2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxSwQxEIX7/IoHykWLCHelxDSHtjbaCRKyownsJpDJuXD439fZ21UsTidF4DHvmzdz5Dg5MKyFvn980MAFnpngwSm/94QQffWhUYVmDc9okfCWesp@oBs8xcSIVKkrAWNNjZaOUDpCKz/d4Mlae2nW9@o2W7jNbpKZqtVDDr4RDMNsJYxkqDSUDyFUn3oJgkyj/MKqZTgB1ZGjtO4c3FUj4beOap2Z1/jEqpRDU4pCLLMOfbeUXiSTofff2zFKXhm3eAl6NqgxwATYX@x/nDLrrFP0P50pL8fBGSdONd/oCw)

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), `zsh -x`, 10 bytes

```sh
<<<$_$_$_
```

`-x` flag enables xtrace. This again requires a single-character filename.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxSwQxEIX7/IoHitEigldK3Ea0tdFOkJAdTWA3gZmcK4f/fZ29PcXidFIEHu97b5KdpLmDwHvYu4d7C5zgSQgBksvbQIgpcIiNGFYsgqAlwmseqISRLvGYsiARU18jJs6NVkesPaHVHzdk9t6fvizHzNpkGm9LDI3gBO5KV9BmprG@K8chD1qPQpPemsB13MeYnSS4D3VvOnTnjTS49cSM7mxzgU8clLptxlBMddFhb9axq@QK7O33swS1HDKu8RztApgpwkX4X9n/kNp1lFT9TzKX9VdwhMR@VJq/AA)

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `zsh -JNTwEDY`, 12 bytes

```sh
<<<$->&1 >&2
```

Shortest `-flag` answer with no filename requirement. Sets more flags, and `$-` prints them all. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZAxTwMxDIX3@xVPompgCFI7opCFloEBljIgsUQ5QyLdJVKcclLFfz98vYIYCl4sPfl7z/aBw2jBMAZq@3SvgAs8M8GBY3rvCD644nylAsUKjlED4S12lFxP19iFyAhUqM0eQ4mV5gmfW0LNP9Pg0Riz0Ha5gl2uR8lqatkn7ypBM/RKlpDsQn3@ELK42MkCSDRIF4@S@6NRc@AA/fC4G7abF2HWFvaykgTUlkqZzK/wiZOS97VpyIc86VC3c6lZ0gnq7vs8Rk4njxu8ejUBzeChPcwv739IyTpLiv4nGdP8HZwhcazpWV8)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (Firefox 54), 34 bytes

```
alert((f=function(x)1234)(56)+f+f)
```

Outputs:

```
1234function(x)1234function(x)1234
```

And it sends this warning to the browser console:

```
expression closures are deprecated
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6al0m.png) in my copy of Firefox Developer Edition (54.0a2). It may work in other versions of Firefox as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 48 characters

```
IO=1;puts ?a*48;# let's make it 48 bytes long :)
```

Outputs

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Warns

```
r.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant IO
```

(the file is r.rb, I removed the path, if you run it from irb, you'll get (irb):1: warning...)

There is the warn method in Ruby, but it just outputs its arguments to $stderr, making it look less like a warning.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 57 bytes

Other interpreters may display the warning differently. This was only tested to work on TIO.

```python
from warnings import*
print("prt"*19)
warn("Warning...!")
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59WlJ@rUJ5YlJeZl16skJlbkF9UosVVUJSZV6KhVFBUoqRlaKnJBVKgoRQOUaanp6eopPn/PwA)

**Output**

```
prtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprtprt
```

**Warning**

```
.code.tio:3: UserWarning: Warning...!
  warn("Warning...!")
```

Note that the leading spaces are not counted toward the byte count. If the leading spaces were not ignored, this could be done in 51 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
Screen(console.log(Function));
```

prints

```
ƒ Function() { [native code] }
```

in Chrome, and then throws

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

### My original 32 byte solution:

```
(x=y=>console.log(x+!0+10)||z)()
```

first, prints

```
y=>console.log(x+!0+10)||ztrue10
```

And throws the error

```
ReferenceError: z is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA, 39 Bytes

Not sure if this qualifies, given the compiler constraint, but:

**Input:** (in the immediate window)

```vba
For i=1 To 39:a=a & Chr(i):Next:Print a
```

*<sub>The output includes non-printing characters that don't play well in this window.</sub>

Comment: VBA does not give any compiler warnings so I do not think that this counts a being valid

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 10 bytes

```perl6
dd say 1e9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z8lRaE4sVLBMNXy/38A)

Prints `1000000000` to STDOUT, and `Bool::True` to STDERR. Both produce a trailing newline, but trailing whitespace is ignored in this challenge. `dd` is a Rakudo specific [debugging function](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#Dumper_function_dd)